# Displaying a progress bar and linking it to a download

Tags: java, swing

I am downloading a large file from the internet within my code and would like to show the user a progress bar to show how far along the download is, preferably in a separate pop-up box.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I don't really know where to start, that's the problem.  Tutorials I've found don't sea to link the bar to anything but a delay.  I don't want that, I want it to know how far along the download is.

Comment: How would you go about linking it to a delay?

Comment: The have a delay of 1000 then increment the counter which is linked to the bar.  I can't see how that can be linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See javax.swing.ProgressMonitorInputStream.

People seem to miss this. Maybe it's because it doesn't start with 'J'. ;-)

Comment: I've implemented it and it seams so much nicer than anything else I've been able to find but it doesn't display a pop-up like the link described. My task is taking around 10 seconds and yet it never displays anything.

ProgressMonitorInputStream pin = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(null, fileName, is);

When "is" is the input stream. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Not sure the null is kosher. You can get the underlying ProgressMonitor and prime it with data, e.g. expected maximum, time to pop up, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What UI framework do you use? In case it is Swing, you could wrap your download code into SwingWorker and update progress bar on buffer writes. You could also store written byte count in local variable and utilize Timer, however it seems less elegant (but working).

If my assumption about Swing is correct, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swingworker) has good SwingWorker example to help start you with.

Comment: Yes I am using swing an that example is quite helpful a few things which are still confusing me, however; In their example they use Document. I don't really understand what that is for in the SwingWorker initialisation.

Comment: This is extended example using generics (you can utilize SwingWorker in simplistic way if you want, e.i. without generic parameters). In short: first generic defines type of the object which will be returned upon worker completion, second generic parameter is used for intermediate result storage.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/15152-swingworker-my-small-internet-page-downloader.html